# EC2 auto scaling with elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, high-availability, autoscaling, elastic-ip

I have deployed an auto scaling EC2 and has associated an Elastic IP address with it. I'm not using a load balancer, because the total number of users doesn't exceed 20. Therefore, my current settings are to have **1 minimum** and **1 maximum** servers.

If the EC2 server fails, another one is created instead, which is what i'm trying to do. However, the elastic IP is not automatically remapped to the newly created server.

How can i assign the elastic IP automatically to the newly created EC2 instance? Is there a workaround this issue?

**UPDATE:**

I've added the following to User Data, but the new EC2 is created **without a public ip** still.

```
#!/bin/bash
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --allocation-id=eipalloc-**.***.***.***
```

Comment: I think you need to just drop the quotes honestly.

Comment: still doesn't assign a public ip

Answer (score 2):

Without an ELB to manage your Elastic IPs, you'll need to use the User Data field on your EC2 instance to call the `aws ec2 associate-address` API endpoint upon instance creation:

```
aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id <instance id> --allocation-id <eip-alloc-id>
```

The EIP allocation ID can be found using the AWS Console. You can obtain the Instance ID by making this call in the User Data:

```
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
```

Comment: Try dropping the quotes around `INSTANCE_ID` as @DrSatan1 recommended

Comment: Also, you should change `--AllocationId` to `--allocation-id` - see the parameter list here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/associate-address.html

Comment: I've implemented suggested edits, but still it doesn't assign a public ip

Comment: It added a public ip, but not the EIB

Comment: You can view error output in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`. Make sure you have assigned an IAM Role to the instance so that it has permission to call `aws ec2 associate-address`, and specify a `--region` when making the call. With both of those, it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

With EC2 & Auto scaling, You need using `user data` in EC2 to Auto Attach Elastic IP to EC2 Instance For Auto scaling

```
#!/bin/bash
aws configure set aws_access_key_id "XYZ..."
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key "ABC..."
aws configure set region "ap-..."
aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id "$(curl -X GET "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id")" --public-ip your_elastic_IP
```

**Note: you should create new user & IAM have only permission associate-address to create/get aws key**

Hope it be help you :)